# Neovim config error: '<eof>' expected near 'local'

Tags: linux, macos, windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim

I'm setting up Neovim like this guy in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdn_pKJUda8&t=145s&ab_channel=JoseanMartinez

I'm using WSL - Windows subsystem for Linux.

And I have this error in `~/.config/nvim/lua/suleiman/plugins-setup.lua` file:

```
Error detected while processing /home/suleiman/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim/_init_packages.lua:0:
/home/suleiman/.config/nvim/lua/suleiman/plugins-setup.lua:24: '<eof>' expected near 'local'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        vim/_init_packages.lua: in function <vim/_init_packages.lua:0>
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/suleiman/.config/nvim/init.lua:1: in main chunk
```

And here is the file itself:

```
vim.cmd([[
  augroup packer_user_config
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost plugins.lua source <afile> | PackerCompile
  augroup end
]])

local status, packer = pcall(require, 'packer')
if not status then
  return
end

return packer.startup(function(use)
  use('wbthomason/packer.nvim')
  
  use('bluz71/vim-nightfly-guicolors')


  if packer_bootstrap then
    require('packer').sync()
  end
end)

local ensure_packer = function()   // This is the line:24
  local fn = vim.fn
  local install_path = fn.stdpath('data')..'/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim'
  if fn.empty(fn.glob(install_path)) > 0 then
    fn.system({'git', 'clone', '--depth', '1', 'https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim', install_path})
    vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]
    return true
  end
  return false
end

local packer_bootstrap = ensure_packer()

return require('packer').startup(function(use)
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
  -- My plugins here
  -- use 'foo1/bar1.nvim'
  -- use 'foo2/bar2.nvim'

  -- Automatically set up your configuration after cloning packer.nvim
  -- Put this at the end after all plugins
  if packer_bootstrap then
    require('packer').sync()
  end
end)
```

plugins-setup.lua

And this is here is the `~/.config/nvim/init.lua` file where I `require` that file:

```
require('suleiman.plugins-setup')
require('suleiman.core.options')
require('suleiman.core.keymaps')
require('suleiman.core.colorscheme')
```

I searched on this error, I didn't find the solution.

There isn't supposed to be an error at all I think, because I copied what that guy on that video did.

Comment: Still don't know the solution.

Comment: Based on a similar problem I just had and on [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37415), I'm pretty sure it's complaining about the `ensure_packer` function being declared after the `return packer.startup (...)`. It's an unreachable line.